# Package wrapping "odbc" doesn't work with a global connection

Tags: r, package, devtools

I have a package `pkg` which wraps around the `odbc` package to simplify my life. The package is composed of a single code file `sql_con.R`:

```
# sql_con.R
getQuery <- function(sql) {
  con <- odbc::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                   Driver = "SQL Server",
                   Server = "Foo",
                   UID = "user",
                   PWD = "password")
  return(odbc::dbGetQuery(con, sql))
}

# DESCRIPTION
Package: NCHUtils
Title: What the Package Does (One Line, Title Case)
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: 
    person(given = "First",
           family = "Last",
           role = c("aut", "cre"),
           email = "first.last@example.com",
           comment = c(ORCID = "YOUR-ORCID-ID"))
Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
License: What license it uses
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Depends: 
    odbc

# NAMESPACE
exportPattern("^[^\\.]")
importMethodsFrom(odbc, dbGetQuery, dbConnect)
```

Building this package works correctly, `library(pkg)` followed by some SQL call using `getQuery()` gives good results.

However, having to create a new connection with each query is a bit silly, so I want to make `con` a global variable which is only created once and reused every time. (This will be later improved upon using the `pool` package). I've also put the connection in an environment to get over any binding locking issues (following the suggestion in [this R-bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/global-variables-in-r-packages/)).

```
# sql_con.R version 2.0
pkg <- new.env()

pkg$con <- odbc::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                   Driver = "SQL Server",
                   Server = "Foo",
                   UID = "user",
                   PWD = "password")

getQuery <- function(sql) {
  return(odbc::dbGetQuery(pkg$con, sql))
}
```

Building the package is once again successful.

I then run the following tests:

```
library(pkg)

pkg::pkg
# <environment: 0x000001a9dbcf8f88>

pkg::pkg$con
# An object of class "Microsoft SQL Server"
# [a bunch of attributes...]

pkg::getQuery("SELECT * FROM Foo")
# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
#   unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbGetQuery’ for signature ‘"Microsoft SQL Server", "character"’
```

Removing the use of an environment changes nothing. I've already set DESCRIPTION to use `Depends:` instead of the common `Imports:` in an attempt to fix this (the first version worked with `Imports:`), and am (afaik) importing the function correctly with `importMethodsFrom` in NAMESPACE.

I've noticed `odbc` creates the inherited function with the "Microsoft SQL Server" signature only once `dbGetQuery()` is actually called with such an argument. But I can't see how that'd be relevant.

Is there any reason why making the connection global breaks the package?

Comment: ["If a package uses S4 classes and methods exported from another package, but does not import the entire namespace of the other package, it needs to import the classes and methods explicitly, with directives ..."](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Namespaces-with-S4-classes-and-methods)  might be relevant.

Comment: @Roland, changing "Imports:" to "Depends:" in DESCRIPTION and adding `import(odbc)` (and/or `importFrom("odbc", dbGetQuery, dbConnect)`) to NAMESPACE had no effect.

Comment: The info in Roland's link, right below the text he quoted, clearly states that the directives are `importClassesFrom` and `importMethodsFrom`.

Comment: @Alexis, yes. However, adding `importMethodsFrom(odbc, dbGetQuery, dbConnect)` throws the same error when getQuery() is called.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Have you configured everything as described in the [README](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/blob/master/README.md)?

Comment: @Alexis, Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 17134). And I believe I have configured everything correctly, yes. As I said, if I `source` my package code (instead of importing it with `library` or `require`), everything works just fine. I just can't get it to work as a package, and I don't see anything in the README specific to packages.

Comment: Also note that the error message I get when running `getQuery` after importing the package states "unable to find [...] for signature "Microsoft SQL Server" [...]". So the `dbConnect` call is clearly successful since dbGetQuery is receiving an object which identifies itself as Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce the problem, though I used a different driver. `importFrom` was enough in my case, but if you already tried `import(odbc)` then that shouldn't be the root cause. Can you load `odbc`, connect to your database, and post the output of `showMethods("dbGetQuery")`?

Comment: @Alexis, I get `Function: dbGetQuery (package DBI)
conn="DBIConnection", statement="character"
conn="OdbcConnection", statement="character"`. However, if I then actually use `dbGetQuery` and run `showMethods` again, a new item is added to the list: `conn="Microsoft SQL Server", statement="character"
    (inherited from: conn="OdbcConnection", statement="character")`. So the SQL Server signature is apparently only generated on use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have an ODBC connection right now,
but I think I know what the problem is.

I came across [this thread](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/proper-use-of-reg-finalizer-to-close-connections-td4698838.html),
which I suggest you read through because you might need something similar to clean your connections,
but the key insight is:

> Note that when you install a package, R runs all the code in the 
>   package and only stores the results of the code in the installed 
>   package. So if you create an object outside of a function in your 
>   package, then only the object will be stored in the package, but not 
>   the code that creates it. The object will be simply loaded when you 
>   load the package, but it will not be re-created.

That means that your package is trying to use a DB connection that was serialized and subsequently deserialized,
which can't possibly work.
If you wanted to manage it entirely by yourself,
you'd probably need something like:

```
conn_provider <- with(new.env(), {
    conn <- NULL

    function() {
        if (is.null(conn)) {
            conn <<- DBI::dbConnect(your_details)
        }

        conn
    }
})
```

And a `reg.finalizer` call like explained in the linked thread.

Regarding package imports,
from what I can gather,
the generics are defined by `DBI`,
and different packages build upon it,
so I think you're better off importing the generics from `DBI` and the methods from `odbc`.
If you use `roxygen2` (which you definitely should),
you'd need something along the lines of:

```
#' @importFrom DBI dbGetQuery
#' @importMethodsFrom odbc dbGetQuery
#'
getQuery <- function(sql) {
  DBI::dbGetQuery(conn_provider(), sql)
}
```

And similarly for all your other functions.
*I think* that this way,
the calls to `DBI` generics in your package can always dispatch to the specific methods defined by any package that builds upon `DBI`,
not just `odbc` ones.

Comment: Success! Indeed, changing from a global variable in an environment to this `conn_provider` generator did the trick. I didn't actually have to change `odbc::` to `DBI::` nor add DBI to my NAMESPACE (which is what roxygen2 does), though. And yes, I certainly intend to use roxygen.

Comment: @Wasabi You don't *need* to change to `DBI::` right now, but if you ever want to use a non-ODBC driver, you'll have to. That's why I suggested that.